# Way of passing API data to the view asynchronously?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I'm super new to Laravel and I was wondering what the best optimization for the following issue would be.

Right now I have a call to an external API to a project management application that retrieves a list of tasks. This call occurs in my controller and the data is then passed to a dashboard view to be rendered with Vue. I'd normally just have this API call happen entirely on the front-end, but the project management application uses OAuth 2, so I'm authenticating and calling the endpoint on the server-side.

This technically works fine, but sometimes loading my app's dashboard takes a little longer to load than I'd like. I believe the culprit is the fact that the page makes the API call on each reload.

My question is this: is there a way to pass the API response data to the view asynchronously? In my ideal scenario the view would load with just a loading icon and then show the tasks once they were received from the project management server. Like I said: I'd know how to do this using AJAX and the like, but there's an access token and OAuth involved.

Hopefully that makes sense and isn't a totally silly question, but any suggestions at this time would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technicaly, you can't make asynchronous response in one shot. If you want to send "structure" then data, you'll have to make an another request.

Indeed you could use Ajax, or you could try socket with something like Laravel-echo which allows you to broadcast events. You'll have to add the bearerToken
to your "Echo" instance.

[Here the link to laravel-echo documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting)

[and here an example using Echo & Passport](https://medium.com/@marques.joaopereira/laravel-echo-laravel-echo-server-api-authentication-using-passport-1d6b847f91c6)

Comment: Yes, ajax seems to be the simpliest approch to success your goal. Vuejs and axios will help you a lot; Your controller serve the view then vuejs call another controller (a specific endpoint) to retrieve third party api data; during the second call, vuejs could display a loader.

Answer (score 0):

Took your advice about AJAX:
Ended up loading the view without making the API call. Then, once the view and Vue component was mounted, made an axios get request to a controller, which made the API request to the project management tasks and returned that data to the view. Sometimes it's hard to see how simple the solution is when you've been staring at a problem for so long. Thanks all!